# Find a element and append a image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know how to append a image to a known tag.  e.g.

```
//html
<div class="ImageContainer"></div>    

//JS
var image = new Image;
image.src = '/Public/Images/image.png';
image.appendTo($('.ImageContainer'));
```

but how to find a certain tag(the figure tag here) and append the image?

I could locate the figure tag with '.find()':

```
var ImageContainer = $('<div><figure></figure></div>').
console.log(ImageContainer.find('figure').html());
```

but failed to append the image to it:

```
image.appendTo(ImageContainer.find('figure')); //doesn't work
```

Comment: what is `cardContainer`?

Comment: And a sidenote your image variable should be wrapped inside `$(image)` to get appended! [example](http://jsfiddle.net/k0q8r6zv/)

Comment: I see!  `ImageContainer.find('figure').append(image)` works instead of `image.appendTo(ImageContainer.find('figure'));`

Comment: hmm `$(image).appendTo(ImageContainer.find('figure'))` will work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an image element with an id you can select it like so:

```
var $image = '<img src="/Public/Images/image.png" />';
```

Then so find the figure elemnt:

```
$(ImageContainer).find('figure').append($image);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

1) Stored image url in variable name $img.

2) Find the div using class name 'image' ($('.image'))

3) Appended image to div

**HTML**

```
<div class="image"> </div>
```

**JS**

```
var $img = '<img src="https://skypeblogs.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/skype-button.png"/>';

$('.image').append($img);
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/uf3yy4fs/)**

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery, you can just do

```
var htmlString = '<div><figure><img src="some image src" /></figure></div>';
$('#ImageContainer').html(htmlString);
```

but if you are wanting to insert the div/figure and image separately, then you'd be best giving it some sort of identifier, i.e.

```
var htmlString = '<div><figure id="myFig"></figure></div>';
$('#ImageContainer').html(htmlString);
$('#myFig').html('<img src="" />');
```